# Php 404 page redirection

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble setting the redirect page. It doesn't seem to load.

Currently I have this
it does the cases for the pages but it doesnt go to the defualt for some reason ??
comes up with page does not exists.

this bit is not working it wont switch to the default for some reason ?

```
   //get the page information
    $pageInfo = $model -> getPageInfo($_GET['page']);

    //select which page to include when the user clicks
    //on either register/home/my account/my bids/my sell/completed auctions/edit etc..etc..etc..
    switch($_GET['page']) {

        case 'Register':
            include 'views/register.php';
            $view = new HomeView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'Home':
            include 'views/homeView.php';
            $view = new HomeView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'My Account':
            include 'views/myaccount.php';
            $view = new myaccount($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'My Bids':
            include 'views/mybids.php';
            $view = new Mybids($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'My Sell':
            include 'views/mysell.php';
            $view = new mysell($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'Completed Auctions':
            include 'views/checkout.php';
            $view = new checkout($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'editProduct':
            include 'views/editProductView.php';
            $view = new EditProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'addProduct':
            include 'views/addProductView.php';
            $view = new AddProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'deleteProduct':
            include 'views/deleteProductView.php';
            $view = new DeleteProductView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;

        case 'deleteUser':
            include 'views/deleteUserView.php';
            $view = new DeleteUserView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;

        case 'search':
            include 'views/search.php';
            $view = new search($pageInfo, $model);
        break;   

        case 'product':
            include 'views/productView.php';
            $view = new ProductView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;

        default: 
            include 'views/404.php';
            $view = new error($pageInfo,$model);
        break;
```

Comment: What if `$_GET['page']` is not set?, you are not even checking for that one

Comment: try `var_dump($_GET); die();` and see what are you getting

Comment: $pageInfo = $model -> getPageInfo($_GET['page']);
    
        //select which page to include when the user clicks
        //on either register/home/my account/my bids/my sell/completed auctions/edit etc..etc..etc..
        switch($_GET['page']) {
            
then begins the switch and etc of all the cases but default wont load

Answer (score 0):

1st: I don't think you need `break;` for the `default:` directive,

second, I would add, the following if I were you.

```
if(!$_GET['page'] && empty($_GET['page'])){
include 'views/404.php';
$view = new error($pageInfo,$model);

}
```

So, if page id, is not set, you can only echo, what the default, would give out

Comment: Your code is fine, just include mine before your codes, and see what happens.

Comment: it says this page does not exists? when i try to enter a random url http://localhost/school/Tradingpost1v/Tradingpost%20Serverside/www/index.php?page=Register22

Comment: try as the same method as the above user told, you. If 404.ph and the page that has this script are on the same folder, then use only `404.php` without `views`

Comment: same result page does not exsit

Comment: case 'product':
                include 'views/productView.php';
                $view = new ProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;
        
            default: 
                include 'views/404.php';
                $view = new error($pageInfo,$model);
        
        if(!$_GET['page'] && empty($_GET['page'])){
include 'views/404.php';
$view = new error($pageInfo,$model);

}

Comment: Does it give you the same content which you have written in the 404.php ?

Comment: Give me the complete URL address you typed in, before when you get this error

Comment: http://localhost/school/Tradingpost1v/Tradingpost%20Serverside/www/index.php?page=Home234

Comment: you are checking home=234, but that is not set

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET['page']){
    switch ($_GET['page']) {
    case 'product':
        include 'views/productView.php';
        $view = new ProductView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;
    default:
        include 'views/404.php';
        $view = new error($pageInfo,$model);
    }
}
```

Should work.
make sure you add some extra verification into the `if($_GET...` check

Comment: it came up with this page goes not exist? :(

Comment: Try: include './views/404.php';